# Quel est le mot le plus long d’une syllabe ?

Tags: orthographe

Le français comporte beaucoup de lettres muettes qui peuvent amener à former des mots très longs et pour autant d’une seule syllabe.

Sur un autre forum, j’ai croisé le mot Schtroumpfs (11 lettres), mais aucune source officielle atteste quel est le mot d’une seule syllabe le plus long dans la langue française.

Your thoughts?

Comment: You may find an answer here: https://chrplr.github.io/openlexicon/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pour rester dans le bleu :

> Ces schtroumpfs [schtroumpfent](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/schtroumpfent) (13 lettres)

Si on ne se limite pas à ce qu'on peut trouver dans un dictionnaire mais accepte tout ce qui a pu être imprimé, il n'y a pas de limite définie, par exemple 64, 47 et 61 lettres [ici](https://books.google.fr/books?id=TsFDDwAAQBAJ&lpg=PT42&dq=nooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooon&hl=fr&pg=PT43#v=snippet&q=noooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooon&f=false):

[image]

Comment: Ces schtroumpfs schtroumpferaient.  :)

Comment: @MaxD Non, ça ne schtroumpfe pas. Il y a trois syllabes...

Comment: @jilliagre C'est vrai, j'ai fait une erreur!!

Answer (score 5):

Si on a le droit de conjuguer les verbes, alors

> Ils schlinguent

donne 11 lettres.

Answer (score 4):

[Schlittes](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlitte) (9 lettres au pluriel) me semble tenir une bonne place.

Answer (score 3):

J'ai suivi la suggestion de Dimitris, et voilà le résultat.
Il manque toutefois quelques propositions comme "schtroumpfent" ou "schlinguent".

```
   ortho       nbsyll nblettres
   <chr>        <int>     <int>
 1 schtroumpfs      1        11
 2 brouillent       1        10
 3 grouillent       1        10
 4 schlingues       1        10
 5 schtroumpf       1        10
 6 souhaitent       1        10
 7 tchatchent       1        10
 8 bouillent        1         9
 9 braillent        1         9
10 branchent        1         9
```

Answer (score 1):

Je participe à ce "golf inversé" avec deux propositions (déjà battues par les autres réponses, mais je trouve ces mots intéressants) :

- [**Pschents**](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/pschent/64734?q=Pschents#64009) (8 lettres)

> (*au pluriel*) Coiffure des pharaons, formée par la réunion des 2 couronnes (mitre blanche de la Haute-Égypte et mortier de couleur rouge de la Basse-Égypte).

- [**Ouailles**](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/ouaille/56845?q=ouailles#56517) (8 lettres)

> Fidèles par rapport au pasteur spirituel.